# Is there a maximum number of tripwires I can set?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

When trying to fight an exceptionally difficult enemy in a Cauldron I came up with the *genius* idea to use my resources to make over a hundred shock tripwires to constantly immobilize it.

Will this be possible or do tripwires despawn after a certain number have been placed? If so, how many can be down at one time?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, there unfortunately is a limit on how many tripwires you can have at any given time. The maximum you can have placed is 16. When attempting to place a 17th, the oldest tripwire will disappear.

You can see this happen in this short video I recorded:

Comment: I wonder if this is true of all placeables and whether the maximum number of each placeable is related at all to the maximum number your pack can currently hold.  (How many tripwires could your pack hold when you tried this?)

Comment: @dg99 I could hold 12 tripwires when I did this. I believe that is the maximum you can hold for tripwires.

Comment: Ugh ... turns out it's worse than this.  The limit is on all placeables combined.  So the total traps AND tripwires (and maybe even proximity grenades) you can put out at once is 16. :(

Comment: Any idea if this applies to the PC version also?

Comment: Yes, this applies to the PC version too.

Comment: As per @slacktide 's answer, this does also apply to pc.