# How many traps and wires I can place in Horizon: Zero Dawn on PC, and how to increase the limit?

Tags: pc, horizon-zero-dawn

I'll try to keep the question as spoiler free as possible, but if you haven't played the game, especially caldurons, I advised caution.

So yesterday I was in a situation I knew I'll have to fight enemy that's too strong for me to take heads on. I had time to prepare so I started settings up traps and blast wires. To my surprise, when I added a trap I've seen one of the wires disappear just in front of my eyes. I set my traps in a pattern I can recreate, so I went to the next wire, put down a trap and wire blinked out of existence. I did it a couple more times just to be sure.

So my question is twofold:

1. What is the limit, or what it depends on?
2. How to increase it?

I was far from being out of RAM or VRAM. I checked that.

Comment: I see now it might be a duplicate of https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/302018/66113 but I'm more interested in knowing how to increase the limit. I'll try to rephrase question later, real life makes it difficult now.

Comment: It's definitely a dupe, and there's no way to increase that as far as I know.

Comment: I think this is probably a limitation of the game engine / game design. I notice that on Horizon Forbidden West the limit is part of the skill tree and is much lower!